# Getting Ubuntu 16.04 on a ZFS root on a Hetzner dedicated server

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, zfsonlinux, hetzner

By now, it's well possible to get Ubuntu 16.04 running on a ZFS root-fs. Ubuntu 16.04 has ZFS in the default package manager, and with guides like [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ZFS), it's not hard to get started.

However, all guides I've seen require being able to boot from a Ubuntu installation image. For a Hetzner dedicated server, this is an uncommon installation procedure, as it requires engineers to visit the server and plug-in a remote KVM.

By default, the dedicated servers boot into a rescue system, which allows to install a variety of Linux distributions through their 'installiamge' script. However, this script does not support ZFS yet.

How to get a Hetzner dedicated server running on a ZFS root?

Answer (score 12):

The basic idea is to get Ubuntu installed on a small partition on the harddrive, partition the hard-drive to use the remainder of the space for ZFS, and then copy the installation over. I'm mainly using [this guide](https://blog.heckel.xyz/2016/12/31/move-existing-linux-install-zfs-root/) on instructions how to do that.

Lazy, and experience with Ansible? I wrote a little stack of scripts to automate these steps. They are available on: https://github.com/tijszwinkels/hetzner-ubuntu-16.04-zfs-root-ansible/blob/master/hetzner-ubuntu-16.04.yml 
Be careful, these scripts assume that the host is booted into the Hetzner rescue system, and they will wipe your drives as a very first step. Use at your own risk!

```
# SSH into the host.

# Wipe the drives. Assuming SSDs on 'sda' and 'sdb'.
/sbin/blkdiscard /dev/sda
/sbin/blkdiscard /dev/sdb

# Install Ubuntu 16.04 on a 4G partition using the Hetzner 'installimage' script
/root/.oldroot/nfs/install/installimage -a -n my-hostname -r yes -l 1 -p /:ext4:4G -K /root/.ssh/robot_user_keys -i /root/.oldroot/nfs/install/../images/Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal.tar.gz

# Reboot the system.
/sbin/shutdown -r now

# Wait for the host to come back up, and SSH in.

# Install the 'parted' parition editor
apt-get update && apt-get install -y parted

# Run parted on the first drive, create a partition in all remaining space. (UNTESTED!)
sudo parted /dev/sda
(parted) mkpart primary 4097MB -1s
(parted) quit

# Run parted on the second drive, create a partition in all remaining space. (UNTESTED!)
sudo parted /dev/sdb
(parted) mkpart primary 4097MB -1s
(parted) quit

# Install required ZFS packages
apt-get install -y zfs-dkms zfs-initramfs

# Create a ZFS pool named 'tank'
# Please note that I'm using the /dev/disk/by-id interface. This is more resilient than /dev/sda and /dev/sdb
zpool create -f -o ashift=13 -O atime=off -O dedup=off -O compression=lz4  tank mirror `ls /dev/disk/by-id/ata-*-part2` 

# Create OS partiton
zfs create tank/os

# Rsync the current system to the new partition.
rsync -a --one-file-system / /tank/os/

# Chroot into the system
cd /tank/os
mount --bind /dev dev
mount --bind /proc proc
mount --bind /sys sys
mount --bind /run run
chroot .

# Install GRUB into the drives
export ZPOOL_VDEV_NAME_PATH=YES
update-grub
grub-install /dev/sda
grub-install /dev/sdb
```

Now, you should have a Hetzner dedicated server that happily boots into Ubuntu 16.04 with a ZFS root fs. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was a time saver ! The only thing missing (which I found in your link) was to install zfs (`apt install zfs-dkms zfs-initramfs`). Also in my case, there was no disk with id `ls /dev/disk/by-id/ata-*-part2` so I used good old `/sdXy`

Comment: Thank you for sharing back your findings! - I added the instructions for installing the packages. I personally prefer the /dev/disk/by-id interface, as it's supposedly more robust to moving drives around onto other ports or initialization order, but no idea whether that's an issue in practice.

Comment: Thanks, that also worked for Debian 9 (using the GUI installimage and then starting from the apt-get command) except for one important detail: I had to do additionally is to `zfs set mountpoint=/ tank/os` before the final reboot. Without that zfs in the initramfs tried to mount to /root/tank/os which did not work and stopped booting the system.

Answer (score 2):

Magnificent guide, thank you @TinkerTank.

If you are using one of the **newer NVMe Servers** and following this guide, you might want to use these steps and device names instead:

```
# Boot into rescue from Robot
# SSH into the host.

# Wipe the drives. Assuming SSDs on 'sda' and 'sdb'.
# For SSD Servers
#/sbin/blkdiscard /dev/sda
#/sbin/blkdiscard /dev/sdb
# For NVMe Servers
/sbin/blkdiscard /dev/nvme0n1
/sbin/blkdiscard /dev/nvme1n1

# Install Ubuntu 16.04 on a 16G partition using the Hetzner 'installimage' script
# For Ubuntu 18.04 it should be this, but FAILS TO BOOT
#/root/.oldroot/nfs/install/installimage -a -n my-hostname -r yes -l 1 -p /:ext4:16G -K /root/.ssh/robot_user_keys -i /root/.oldroot/nfs/install/../images/Ubuntu-1804-bionic-64-minimal.tar.gz
# For Ubuntu 16.04:
/root/.oldroot/nfs/install/installimage -a -n my-hostname -r yes -l 1 -p /:ext4:16G -K /root/.ssh/robot_user_keys -i /root/.oldroot/nfs/install/../images/Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal.tar.gz
# Press x to continue immediately or wait a few seconds...

# Reboot the system.
#/sbin/shutdown -r now

reboot

# Wait for the host to come back up, and SSH in.
# Update the server
apt update
apt upgrade

# Create a partition on first disk with all the remaining space.
fdisk /dev/nvme0n1
# Press n then accept all defaults and save with w 

# Create a partition on the second disk with all remaining space.
fdisk /dev/nvme1n1
Press n then accept all defaults and save with w 

reboot

# Install required ZFS packages
apt install zfsutils-linux

# Create a ZFS pool named 'tank'
# Please note that I'm using the /dev/disk/by-id interface. This is more resilient than /dev/sda and /dev/sdb
# For SSD servers @hetznet: zpool create -f -o ashift=13 -O atime=off -O dedup=off -O compression=lz4  tank mirror `ls /dev/disk/by-id/ata-*-part2` 
# For NVMe servers:
zpool create -f -o ashift=13 -O atime=off -O dedup=off -O compression=lz4  tank mirror nvme0n1p2 nvme1n1p2

# Create OS partition
zfs create tank/os

# Rsync the current system to the new partition.
rsync -a --one-file-system / /tank/os/

# Chroot into the system
cd /tank/os
mount --bind /dev dev
mount --bind /proc proc
mount --bind /sys sys
mount --bind /run run
chroot .

# Install GRUB into the drives
export ZPOOL_VDEV_NAME_PATH=YES
update-grub
# For SSD Servers:
#grub-install /dev/sda
#grub-install /dev/sdb
# For NVMe servers:
grub-install /dev/nvme0n1p2
grub-install /dev/nvme1n1p2

exit
reboot
```

> Now, you should have a Hetzner dedicated server that happily boots into Ubuntu 16.04 with a ZFS root fs. Good luck!

**Works seamlessly on Ubuntu 16.04, fails to boot on Ubuntu 18.04.
Anyone knows why and how to solve it?**

Notice: instead of 4GB of HDD Space specified in the original tutorial, I launch the initial OS on a 16GB partition. Newer servers come with at least 2 x 512GB NVMe, so you can convert those 2 x 16 partitions onto 2 x 16GB SWAP partitions that Linux kernel will stripe by itself (faster than using one single Raid partition).

Comment: I just installed this with an Ubuntu 16.04 image but I'm unable to reach the SSH after the reboot. What could be the issue?

Comment: BTW does it make sense to create a ZFS mirror _on top_ of a software RAID? Does it have any implications?

Comment: You are not creating a ZFS mirror on top of a software RAID,
You are creating a mirror witha (small) chunk of your disks (which it totally optional),
And then you are creating a ZFS mirror with the remaining of the disk.